# How to Show Interstitial ads When i click on Back Arrow icon

Tags: button, ads, show, interstitial

Arrow Code In Activity Main:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("App Name");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I Already Add the other code Now I need to Show Interstitial When I click The Arrow

Answer (score 1):

The piece of code you are looking for is

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
mInterstitialAd.show()
} else {
<functionYouWanttoRun>}
}
```

If you're using using button you wanna use `onClickListener`